# Creating database using hibernate in postgres

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to create database using native query.

My code:

```
@Service
public class DatabaseService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void create() {
        String sql = "CREATE DATABASE MYDATABASE TEMPLATE PATTERN";
        Query q= em.createNativeQuery(sql);

        q.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

When I run this I get error "insert/update should be run in transaction"

when i add @transacional i get "database cannot be created in transaction"

What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create Connection Object
2. Creating your Statement Object

```
Connection Conn = DriverManager.getConnection(“jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306”);
try {
   Statement Stmt = Conn.createStatement();
   Stmt.execute(“CREATE DATABASE db_name”);
   Stmt.execute(“CREATE TABLE db_name (message char(31))”);
   Stmt.executeUpdate (“INSERT INTO db_name VALUES (”Hello World”)”);
   Conn.commit();
} catch (SQLException exception) {
   Stmt.execute(“OPEN DATABASE db_name”);
} finally {
   Conn.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your query to

String sql = "CREATE DATABASE MYDATABASE ";

as u r creating database.